# how to create set of values, after group function in Pig (Hadoop)

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

Lets say I have set of values in file.txt 
    a,b,c
    a,b,d
    k,l,m
    k,l,n
    k,l,o

And my code is:
    file = LOAD 'file.txt' using PigStorage(',');
    events = foreach file generate session_id, user_id, code, type;
    gr = group events by (session_id, user_id);

and I have set of value:

((a,b),{(a,b,c),(a,b,d)})
((k,l),{(k,l,m),(k,l,n),(k,l,o)})

And I'd like to have:
(a,b,(c,d))
(k,l,(m,n,o))

Have you got any idea how to do it?

Regards
Pawel

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note: you are inconsistent in your question. You say `session_id, user_id, code, type` in the `FOREACH` line, but your have a PigStorage not providing values. Also, that `FOREACH` has 4 values, while your sample data only has 3. I'll assume that `type` doesn't exist in order to answer your question.

---

After your `gr` relation, you are left with the group by key (in this case `(session_id, user_id)`) in a automatically generated tuple called `group`.

So, first step: `gr2 = FOREACH gr GENERATE FLATTEN(group);`
This will give you the tuples `(a,b)` and `(k,l)`. You need to use `FLATTEN` because `group` is a tuple and you are asking for `session_id` and `user_id` to be individual columns. `FLATTEN` does that for you.

Ok, so now modify the `gr2` line to also use a projection to tease out the third value:

```
gr2 = FOREACH gr GENERATE FLATTEN(group), events.code;
```

`events.code` creates a *bag* out of all the `code` values. `events` is the name of the bag of grouped tuples (it's named after the original relation).

This should give you:

```
 (a, b, {c, d})
 (k, l, {m, n, o})
```

It's very important to note that the values in the list are in a bag not a tuple, like you asked for. Keeping it in a bag is the right idea because the bag is a variable list, while a tuple is not.

---

Additional advice: Understanding how `GROUP BY` outputs data is something I see a lot of people struggle with when first using Pig. If you think my answer doesn't make much sense, I'd recommend spending some time to really get to understand `GROUP BY`. Understanding versus thinking it is magic will pay off in the long run.